# MenuListener or ActionListener for menu item

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Here is my code:

```
menuBar = new JMenuBar();
file = new JMenu("File");
options = new JMenu("Options");
help = new JMenu("Help");
editOptions = new JMenu("Change settings...");
close = new JMenu("Exit");

close.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           System.exit(1);
      }
});
```

However, this doesn't work. I've also tried using a menuListener like such:

```
menuBar = new JMenuBar();
file = new JMenu("File");
options = new JMenu("Options");
help = new JMenu("Help");
editOptions = new JMenu("Change settings...");
close = new JMenu("Exit");

close.addMenuListener(new MenuListener() {
      @Override
      public void menuSelected(MenuEvent arg0) {
            System.exit(1);
      }

      @Override
      public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent arg0) {
      }

      @Override
      public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent arg0) {
      }

});
```

But that exited as soon as the menu "exit" was highlighted. I need it to exit when clicked on. Any ideas?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: I would go with a more _"natural"_ solution an just make the exit a `JMenuItem`

Comment: BTW - `close = new JMenu("Exit"); .. System.exit(1);`  should end with `System.exit(0);` since it is a normal program termination.

Comment: Sadly, I have to use the "File -> Exit". Guidelines.

Comment: _"Sadly, I have to use the "File -> Exit". Guidelines"_ - That seems to suggest Exit being a `JMenuItem` of the File `JMenu`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ActionListener does not work becase [JMenu ignores ActionEvent](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4108937).

If you want your program to exit on click at Close button, then use MouseListener:

```
    close.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: That will not react to keyboard input.

Comment: Good because I don't need it to :)

Comment: Thanks a ton PKopachevsky ;)